# Intel realsense SR300 on ROS indigo

Tags: ros, realsense, rgbd

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I am trying to use the sr300 RGBD sensor on ros indigo. I use librealsense(https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense) and realsense_camera(https://github.com/intel-ros/realsense) package that intel provides.

I have encountered two problems.

1. RGB-Depth registration has large errors
2. XYZRGB pointcloud suddenly does not get published, even though rgb and registered depth images get published as normal.

Does anyone have any experience with this sensor? Is there a way to calibrate the sensor and get a better registration? Is there a different package that I can use?

Thank you in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262771/intel-realsense-sr300-on-ros-indigo/) by [angeltop](https://answers.ros.org/users/29793/angeltop/) on ROS Answers with karma: 351 on 2017-05-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A possible solution: [github issues](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/issues/656)

---

Originally posted by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) with karma: 2331 on 2017-09-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0